# A Kafka instance in another process or thread is using this directory

Tags: apache-kafka

T get the following error when running kafka connect distributed :

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hadoop/kafka/bin/../logs/server.log (Permission denied)

[2022-09-27 14:03:29,076] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to acquire lock on file .lock in /home/hadoop/kafka/kafka-data/kafka_logs. A Kafka instance in another process or thread is using this directory.

log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [kafkaAppender].
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hadoop/kafka/bin/../logs/controller.log (Permission denied)

Comment: By the way, Kafka isn't a Hadoop process. Therefore, try making a Unix user named `kafka`. Log files shouldn't be in the user home directories, anyway (/var/log/kafka would be preferred)

Comment: kafka is data ingestion tool, and btw my problem was just related to running kafka server while it's already running

Comment: I know what Kafka is. I was referring to your folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deleting the log directory is not a solution ;
when kafka broker is already run we get this error

for my case i just had to use the right cmd to start distributed